# Use results of Dash Multi-Value Dropdown to return as list of strings that feeds into function

Tags: function, callback, dropdown, plotly-dash

I am trying to use a multi-value dropdown in Dash and use the returned values in a function I've created.
This is what the function is and what it looks like when called:

```
    def create_new_card(self, channel_list, title, start = None, stop = None):
    
########################################################################################
       
    eeg_inst.create_new_card(['Fp1', "C3", "F3","O2", "QuarX"], "Neighborhood 1")
```

I have a drop down with all the choices for 'channel_list' and the user can select multiple:

```
dcc.Dropdown(['Fp1', 'Fp2', 'F3', 'F4', 'C3', 'C4', 'P3', 'P4', 'O1', 'O2', 'F7', 'F8', 'T7','T8', 'P7', 'P8', 
    'Fz', 'Cz', 'Pz', 'M1', 'M2', 'AFz', 'CPz', 'POz', 'AccX', 'AccY','AccZ', 'GyroX', 'GyroY', 'GyroZ', 'QuarW', 'QuarX', 
    'QuarY', 'QuarZ'], placeholder='Select streams:', id='select_stream_dropdown', multi=True)
```

Here is the callback for the drop-down selection:

```
    @app.callback(
    Output('dd-output-container', 'children'),
    Input('select_stream_dropdown', 'value')
)
def add_card_selection(value):
    streams_list = {value}
    new_card = eeg_inst.create_new_card(streams_list,"New Card Based On Selection")
    return new_card
```

Here is the 'dd-output-container' (in case it's necessary):

NOTE: The current children are temporary. I'd like the "All Streams" to stay and the user create what they want.

```
html.Div([ dash_draggable.GridLayout(id='dd-output-container', children=[
       dcc.Graph(figure = eeg_inst.graphStream( "All Streams", ['Fp1', "C3", "F3", 
            "O2"])),
       eeg_inst.create_new_card(['Fp1', "C3", "F3","O2", "QuarX"], "Neighborhood 1"),
       eeg_inst.create_new_card(["C3", "F3","O2"], "Neighborhood 2")
       ]
     )
])
```

I need the callback to return a list of strings to insert into the function. I would like the user to select the desired items from the dropdown, then press a button to create the new card. Would a dcc.Checklist be a better option for this? Can this be achieved in one callback or do I need a callback to return the list of strings and another callback to use that list of strings to create the new card on the push of a button? Just confused on how to go about doing this.